# PGSQL selecting columns on certain conditions

Tags: postgresql

In a table I have 5 columns day1, day2... day5. Records in the table can have all days set to TRUE or few days set to TRUE.
Is there any way in PGSQL to select only those columns of a record which have boolean value as TRUE

Example:
My table is: Course, with columns as Course Name, Day1, Day2, Day3, Day4,Day5 with record set as

```
English,True,False,True,False,True
German,False,False,True,True,True
French,False,True,False,True,True
```

What I need to display as result set is:

```
English,Mon,Wed,Fri
German,Wed,Thu,Fri
French,Tue,Thu,Fri
```

Comment: What's your question could you give us more detail?

Comment: Basically, no. The result set has to have the same number of columns, you can't have one row with 2 columns and another row with 5. Either you do something like a CASE statement on each column to select its value if it's TRUE or NULL otherwise, or you transform it to a single row and in there you only have the field values you want, e.g. `SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', NULLIF(day1, FALSE), NULLIF(day2, FALSE), ...`

Comment: No that's not possible. All rows in query result must have the same number of columns.

Comment: You cannot return a different table structure each time, SQL must know in advance what structure it's working with. Can you give us some more detail? There may be an alternative way to solve the problem you had, instead of fixing the solution attempted.

Comment: You could give an example to make your question more clear.

Comment: Your schema is not great. Those `day` columns should be in their own table like `course | day_num` and a third table `day_num | day_name` then you just `JOIN` your tables and use `array_agg()` or `string_agg()` to get the format you want. The way you have it now is going to require a UNION to achieve the same results and it will be slow as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like the following should do the job. It's a bit ugly because your schema isn't the most awesome. This should work on Postgres 9+

```
SELECT course, string_agg(day, ',') as days_of_week
FROM
    (
        SELECT course, 'Mon' as day FROM yourtable WHERE day1 = 'True'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT course, 'Tue' as day FROM yourtable WHERE day2 = 'True'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT course, 'Wed' as day FROM yourtable WHERE day3 = 'True'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT course, 'Thu' as day FROM yourtable WHERE day4 = 'True'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT course, 'Fri' as day FROM yourtable WHERE day5 = 'True'
    ) sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Function like [`iif`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIf) missed suddenly but you could to create it simply:

```
create or replace function iif(boolean, anyelement, anyelement = null) returns anyelement
  language sql
  immutable
as $$
  select case when $1 is null then null when $1 then $2 else $3 end
$$;
```

then:

```
select
  course_name,
  concat_ws(',', iif(day1,'Mon'), iif(day2,'Tue'), iif(day3,'Wed'), iif(day4,'Thu'), iif(day5, 'Fri'))
from course;
```